# Add Marker with text on Mapbox

Tags: java, android, geojson, mapbox-android

We want to achieve UI like the below image in our application.
We are using Mapbox SDK for showing map and geojson to draw the polyline.
we have drawn the polyline using geojson on Mapbox but the question is how to show the marker points with the number on them?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please try to implement using the below reference

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/circle-layer-clustering/

You have to modify the code as per your requirement.